# How to get assets path using jquery in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

I am using file uploading in my ruby on rails application. And when the file is uploaded, I want to make the link for others so that they can also download that file. I have a folder named `job_attachments` within the assets folder for the file attachments. I want to know how I can get the the path for `job_attachments` using jQuery.

I am doing something like this in my controller:

```
  def uploadattachment
    if(params[:job][:uploaded_data])
        uploaded_io=params[:job][:uploaded_data]
        File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets', 'job_attachments', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |f| 
              f.write(uploaded_io.read) 
        end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :layout=>false , :json => uploaded_io.original_filename}      
    end
end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to put uploaded content into your assets folder. Assets are for things that *you* create that are part of your application. Additionally, `app/assets` isn't directly accessible by clients. I assume you want people to be able to download these files?

Create another folder under public ("uploads", perhaps), and put your files there.

To get the path in jQuery, just return the path from your controller when the file is uploaded. You probably want to turn a hash, rather than a string, since that's a little easier to deal with in jQuery.

```
def uploadattachment
  if(params[:job][:uploaded_data])
      uploaded_io=params[:job][:uploaded_data]
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'job_attachments', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |f| 
            f.write(uploaded_io.read) 
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render :layout=>false , :json => {:path => File.join('uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename}}      
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: The files are uploading perfectly in jobs_attachment folder. Why I need to upload them into public directory ?

Comment: Updated answer. `app/assets` will work in development, but in production mode you can't access those files directly. They get precompiled into `public/assets`. This won't happen for anything you've added after deployment.